# Azure B2C Custom Link in Self Service Page

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I have built a custom Self Service page that we are using for a Customer Profile Page. This Profile page allows the customer to modify some of the basic input. Such as name, email etc.

However I want a custom link that pushes the user into a subjourney.

I have tried a claims provider selector

```
    <OrchestrationStep Order="4" Type="ClaimsExchange">
      <ClaimsProviderSelections>
        <ClaimsProviderSelection TargetClaimsExchangeId="B2CUserProfileUpdateExchange" />
        <ClaimsProviderSelection TargetClaimsExchangeId="CustomLinkExchange" />
      </ClaimsProviderSelections>
      <ClaimsExchanges>
        <ClaimsExchange Id="B2CUserProfileUpdateExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="SelfAsserted-ProfileUpdate" />
      </ClaimsExchanges>
    </OrchestrationStep>

    <OrchestrationStep Order="5" Type="ClaimsExchange">
      <ClaimsExchanges>
        <ClaimsExchange Id="CustomLinkExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="CustomLink" />
      </ClaimsExchanges>
    </OrchestrationStep>
```

The user is already logged in here And are on a custom profile page. But I want a link to push the user into a subjourney and cannot figure it out without doing ALOT of crazy JS that im trying to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to follow the embedded password reset [sample](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/embedded-password-reset)?

Note that adding the link only works on an api.signuporsignin page using the unified content provider.

Comment: Not a forgot password, I have that one working. I want a change password flow. I have already built it and it works fine if i have a checkbox then click continue. But I want a link or a button that an authenticated user can click to move into a subjourney. In this case, its the change password subjourney.

Comment: Understood. But you only add a button (it can look like a link) that interacts with the custom policy from a signuporsignin page. I've never seen an example that invokes this from JS.

Comment: I have edited my page. The user is on a profile page... not a sign in page, the user is already signed in. I want them to SEE the profile page, with a custom link (button) at the bottom that I can use to move them into a subjourney.